# npm install error in ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

i'm trying to install npm but it shows me this error

Error: namespace already exists
Command failed

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLEnpm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! zerotoblockchain-network@0.1.6 prepublish: `mkdirp ./network/dist && composer archive create --sourceType dir --sourceName . -a ./network/dist/zerotoblockchain-network.bna`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
 npm ERR! 
  npm ERR! Failed at the zerotoblockchain-network@0.1.6 prepublish script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

```
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/bashayer/.npm/_logs/2018-07-05T14_29_49_053Z-debug.log
```

Package.json is:

```
{
  "engines": {
    "composer": ""
  },
  "name": "zerotoblockchain-network",
  "version": "0.1.6",
  "description": "Zero to Blockchain tutorial network",
  "networkImage": "https://hyperledger.github.io/composer-sample-networks/packages/basic-sample-network/networkimage.svg",
  "networkImageanimated": "https://hyperledger.github.io/composer-sample-networks/packages/basic-sample-network/networkimageanimated.svg",
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": "mkdirp ./network/dist && composer archive create --sourceType dir --sourceName . -a ./network/dist/zerotoblockchain-network.bna",
    "pretest": "npm run lint",
    "lint": "eslint ./network",
    "postlint": "npm run licchk",
    "licchk": "license-check",
    "postlicchk": "npm run doc",
    "doc": "jsdoc --readme ./README.md --pedantic --recurse -c jsdoc.json -d network/out",
    "test-inner": "mocha -t 0 --recursive && cucumber-js",
    "test-cover": "nyc npm run test-inner",
    "test": "mocha network/test --recursive -t 4000",
    "start": "node index"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/rddill-IBM/ZeroToBlockchain"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "zero",
    "blockchain",
    "tutorial",
    "composer",
    "hyperledger"
  ],
  "author": "Bob Dill, IBM Distinguished Engineer",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "browserfs": "^1.2.0",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "chai-as-promised": "^6.0.0",
    "composer-admin": "^0.16.0",
    "composer-client": "^0.16.0",
    "composer-common": "^0.16.0",
    "composer-connector-embedded": "^0.16.0",
    "composer-cucumber-steps": "^0.16.0",
    "composer-runtime": "^0.16.0",
    "composer-runtime-hlfv1": "^0.16.0",
    "cucumber": "^2.2.0",
    "electron": "^2.0.4",
    "eslint": "^3.6.1",
    "extend": "",
    "istanbul": "^0.4.5",
    "jsdoc": "^3.5",
    "license-check": "^1.1.5",
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
    "mocha": "^3.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "nyc": "^11.0.2"
  },
  "license-check-config": {
    "src": [
      "**/*.js",
      "!./coverage/**/*",
      "!./node_modules/**/*",
      "!./network/out/**/*",
      "!./HTML/js-utils/**/*",
      "!./network/scripts/**/*"
    ],
    "path": "header.txt",
    "blocking": true,
    "logInfo": false,
    "logError": true
  },
  "nyc": {
    "exclude": [
      "coverage/**",
      "network/features/**",
      "network/out/**",
      "network/test/**"
    ],
    "reporter": [
      "text-summary",
      "html"
    ],
    "all": true,
    "check-coverage": true,
    "statements": 100,
    "branches": 100,
    "functions": 100,
    "lines": 100
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.1",
    "cfenv": "^1.0.4",
    "connect-busboy": "0.0.2",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "date-format": "",
    "ejs": "",
    "express": "^4.15.4",
    "express-session": "^1.15.5",
    "fabric-client": "^1.0.2",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "http": "0.0.0",
    "https": "^1.0.0",
    "mime": "^2.0.2",
    "os": "^0.1.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "sleep": "^5.1.1",
    "uuid": "^3.1.0",
    "vcap_services": "^0.3.4",
    "websocket": "^1.0.24"
  }
}
```

npm version 6.1.0
nodejs version v4.2.6
Ubuntu version 16.04 LTS

Comment: Can you post your package.json

Comment: this is part of it, i couldn't submit all of ot.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the JSON file, do not post it as an answer